# Best multi relationship table object type design

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have a table called Feed. That table will keep track social objects of different types (Photos, Events, Statuses, etc...) created by users. Now I have 2 design choices.

### CHOICE 1: objectTypeId, objectId:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feed](
[feedId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[objectTypeId] [int] NULL,
[objectId] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectType](
[typeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [NVARCHAR] NULL
```

)

Object type would then hold a list of all the possible types. 
But I hate this method. Reason is, I cannot enforce referential integrity on the database.

If an object is deleted in one of the tables, the objectId value in Feed is pointing to a non-existing object.

Plus, the Join statement here is a mess. You have to hard code tables with hard values like LEFT JOIN Events ON feed.objectTypeId=2 AND feed.objectId=Events.eventId etc...

### CHOICE 2: ADD eventId NULL, photoId NULL, statusId NULL or any other objectTypeId to Feed Table

PRO: Referential integrity can be enforced. Null columns don't cause much problems since they store nothing. No need to create additional Object Type table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feed](
[feedId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[eventId] [int] NULL,
[photoId] [int] NULL,
[statusId] [int] NULL,
)
```

but this table does not really feel normalized.

So, what is the best way to do what I am trying to do, and accomplish my goals. Referential integrity without having to change the schema every time I add a new object type.

### UPDATE:

Forgot to point out that there exist tables of those objects... I have tables

```
CREATE TABLE [Events](
```

eventId INT,
other cols only dealing with events.
)

```
CREATE TABLE [Photos](
```

photoId INT,
other cols that only deal with photos
)

```
CREATE TABLE [Status](
```

statusId INT,
other cols that only deal with statuses
)

Answer (score 0):

Choice 2 is terrible and will lead to nightmares. You will have to add a new column for every new type of content.

I don't know why you think Choice 1 needs complex joins. To retrieve all Events, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Feed where objectTypeID = 
    (SELECT objectTypeID from ObjectType WHERE name = 'Event')
```

As for referential integrity:

> if an object is deleted in one of the tables, the objectId value in Feed is pointing to a non-existing object.

I don't understand. If the object in Feed is deleted, there are no dangling references. If an ObjectType is deleted, what are you planning to do with the objects of that type?

I'm assuming you realize that the ObjectType table is small, with only one row for each type of object...right?

**Edited to add:**

The additional tables you've mentioned each need a `FeedID` column. You should **not** put the object IDs in the `Feed` table. (This assumes that each object belongs to only one feed.)

Answer (score 0):

If the number of feed types is smaller, will it not be better to have separate table for each of the feed types?

The following could be divided into each of its own table.

1. Photos
2. Events
3. Statuses

Comment: Yes, Tables exist for each Feed type. There is only referenceId in Feed table. I have updated my question to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with similar problems, I've chosen to create a separate table for each type of object.  Each table will have a unique identification, e.g. `PhotoId`, for each row.  It will also have an appropriate foreign reference, e.g. to `FeedId`.  (If objects can be shared then linking tables can be added to allow objects to be in more than one place.)  That allows maximum flexibility to keep the right data in the right place, e.g. `Height` and `Width` may apply to photographs.

Triggers are used to validate and coordinate updates, as needed.

Views can be used to pull together data.  They centralize the connections between tables and can enforce additional rules.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question to indicate that separate tables exist for each object type. All I need is a reference to Feed table.

Comment: @tatipor If you have the three tables then why do you even need a Feed table?  Just let the individual tables have thier own iden.

Comment: Essentially, every photo, event, status created is a Feed Item. a Feed Item can have comments, likes, and other social activities. If I don't have a Feed Items table, then for example if a user wants to comment on a photo, I will have to add a Photo_Comments table. If a user wants to comment on an Event, I would have to add Events_Comments table, etc... and it's not just comments. Let's say 'Likes'. If a user likes a photo, then I would have to add Photo_Likes table. I would rather join those tables into a Feed table. I don't know if you get me here.

Comment: @tatipor You need to use the @ if you want someone to get your comment.  And comments and likes is NOT in you problem statement. An answer can only be as good as the problem statement.